# PostgreSQL index not used for query on IP ranges

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-design, range, gist-index

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2 and have a table of IP ranges. Here's the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE ips (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  begin_ip_num bigint,
  end_ip_num bigint,
  country_name character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT ips_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
```

I've added plain B-tree indices on both `begin_ip_num` and `end_ip_num`:

```
CREATE INDEX index_ips_on_begin_ip_num ON ips (begin_ip_num);
CREATE INDEX index_ips_on_end_ip_num ON ips (end_ip_num );
```

The query being used is:

```
SELECT ips.* FROM ips
WHERE 3065106743 BETWEEN begin_ip_num AND end_ip_num;
```

The problem is that my `BETWEEN` query is only using the index on `begin_ip_num`. After using the index, it filters the result using `end_ip_num`. Here's the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` result:

```
Index Scan using index_ips_on_begin_ip_num on ips  (cost=0.00..2173.83 rows=27136 width=76) (actual time=16.349..16.350 rows=1 loops=1)
Index Cond: (3065106743::bigint >= begin_ip_num)
Filter: (3065106743::bigint <= end_ip_num)
Rows Removed by Filter: 47596
Total runtime: 16.425 ms
```

I've already tried various combinations of indices including adding a composite index on both `begin_ip_num` and `end_ip_num`.

Comment: If IP ranges have a significant impact in the db's target business than you should consider using the [ip4r extension](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/ip4r).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try a [multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html), but with reversed order on the second column:

```
CREATE INDEX index_ips_begin_end_ip_num ON ips (begin_ip_num, end_ip_num DESC);
```

Ordering is mostly irrelevant for a single-column index, since it can be scanned backwards almost as fast. But it is important for multicolumn indexes.

With the index I propose, Postgres can scan the first column and find the address, where the rest of the index fulfills the first condition. Then it can, for each value of the first column, return all rows that fulfill the second condition, until the first one fails. Then jump to the next value of the first column, etc.
This is ***still not very efficient*** and Postgres may be faster just scanning the first index column and filtering for the second. Very much depends on your data distribution.

Either way, [`CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) using the multicolumn index from above *can* help performance:

```
CLUSTER ips USING index_ips_begin_end_ip_num
```

This way, candidates fulfilling your first condition are packed onto the same or adjacent data pages. Can help performance a lot with if you have lots of rows per value of the first column. Else it is hardly effective.
(There are also non-blocking external tools for the purpose: [pg_repack](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack/) or [pg_squeeze](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_squeeze).)

Also, is [autovacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html) running and configured properly or have you run `ANALYZE` on the table? You need current statistics for Postgres to pick appropriate query plans.

What would really help here is a [**GiST index** for a `int8range` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-GIST), available since PostgreSQL 9.2. See:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39599/3684)

**If** your IP ranges can be covered with one of the [built-in network types `inet` or `cidr`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html), consider to replace your two `bigint` columns. Or, better yet, look to the [additional module **ip4r**](https://github.com/RhodiumToad/ip4r) by Andrew Gierth (not in the standard distribution. The indexing strategy changes accordingly.

Barring that, you can check out this related answer on dba.SE with using a sophisticated regime with partial indexes. Advanced stuff, but it delivers great performance:

- [Can spatial index help a “range - order by - limit” query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22500/3684)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've settled with the composite index. Adding `DESC` to `end_ip_num` did make a difference. Just as a side not, the composite index you've mentioned should only work >= 9.2.0, right?

Comment: @ZainZafar: The *multicolumn* (= composite) index I mention works in all versions this side of the millennium (at least since 7.3, probably longer). The linked solution on dba.SE has been tested with 9.1. The range type in combination with a GiST index requires 9.2.

Comment: Tried a multi-column index with reversed second column - postgres still went for seq scan. But GiST index with int8range column is very fast! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly this same problem on a nearly identical dataset from maxmind.com's free geiop table. I solved it using Erwin's tip about range types and GiST indexes. The GiST index was key. Without it I was querying at best about 3 rows per second. With it I queried nearly 500000 rows in under 10 seconds! Since Erwin didn't post detailed instructions on how to do this, I thought I'd add them, here...

First of all, you must add a new column having the range type, note that int8range is required for bigint types. Next set its values appropriately, note that the '[]' parameter indicates to make the range *inclusive* at lower and upper bounds (rtfm). Finally add the index, note that the GiST index is where all the performance advantage comes from.

```
alter table ips add column iprange int8range;
update ips set iprange=int8range(begin_ip_num, end_ip_num, '[]');
create index index_ips_on_iprange on ips using gist (iprange);
```

Having laid the groundwork, you can now use the '<@' contained-by operator to search specific addresses against the table. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-range.html

```
SELECT "ips".* FROM "ips" WHERE (3065106743::bigint <@ iprange);
```

Comment: This worked well! But you need to cast the integer to a bigint (I was getting "No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.")

SELECT "ips".* FROM "ips" WHERE (cast(3065106743 as bigint) <@ iprange);

Comment: Thanks, Adam. Good point. I added a cast to bigint per your suggestion, but used the ::type "syntactic sugar" as it's a bit more concise.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit late to this party, but this is what works really well for me.

Consider installing [ip4r extension](https://github.com/RhodiumToad/ip4r). It basically allows you to define a column that can hold IP ranges. The name of the extension implies it is just for IPv4, but currently it is also support IPv6.

After you populate table with ranges within that column all you need, is to create GIST index:

```
CREATE INDEX ip_zip_ip4_range ON ip_zip USING gist (ip4_range);
```

I have almost 10 million ranges in my database, but queries take fraction of a milisecond:

```
region=> select count(*) from ip_zip ;

  count  
---------
 9566133

region=> explain analyze select * from ip_zip where '8.8.8.8'::ip4 <<= ip4_range;
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on ip_zip  (cost=234.55..25681.29 rows=9566 width=22) (actual time=0.085..0.086 rows=1 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ('8.8.8.8'::ip4r <<= ip4_range)
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ip_zip_ip4_range  (cost=0.00..232.16 rows=9566 width=0) (actual time=0.055..0.055 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ('8.8.8.8'::ip4r <<= ip4_range)
 Planning time: 0.106 ms
 Execution time: 0.118 ms
(7 rows)

region=> explain analyze select * from ip_zip where '254.50.22.54'::ip4 <<= ip4_range;
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on ip_zip  (cost=234.55..25681.29 rows=9566 width=22) (actual time=0.059..0.059 rows=1 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ('254.50.22.54'::ip4r <<= ip4_range)
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ip_zip_ip4_range  (cost=0.00..232.16 rows=9566 width=0) (actual time=0.048..0.048 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ('254.50.22.54'::ip4r <<= ip4_range)
 Planning time: 0.102 ms
 Execution time: 0.145 ms
(7 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your query looks like `WHERE [constant] BETWEEN begin_ip_num AND end_ipnum` or

As far as I know Postgres doesn't have "AND-EQUAL " access plan, so you need to add a composite index on 2 columns as suggested by **Erwin Brandstetter**.

Comment: I've tried using a composite index and it results in a sequential scan.