# Speeding up range queries in Aurora DB

Tags: amazon-aurora

I tried using ideas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407719/postgresql-index-not-used-for-query-on-range/14407839#14407839) and added index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test_ranges ON sometable (start,stop DESC, payload);
```

But query

```
select count(id) from sometable where start > 1326948385000 and stop < 1326948385001;
```

remains very slow. Is there a way to speed up ranged queries in Aurora?

*Update.* Should I switch to Postgress engine?

Answer (score 0):

Switched to Postgress engine and used `tsrange` field and `gist` index.