# Query with small LIMIT gets slow with many hits

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, postgresql-performance

I have a slow Postgres query and I may need better indexes. But I lack  experience with indexing, so I just indexed foreign keys. I use Postgres 14.3 and Django 3.0.

This is the slow query. It's only slow when the chat room has a lot of messages (like 10k+).

```sql
SELECT
    chat_message.info_date_str,
    auth_user.username,
    chat_message.id,
    chat_message.text_msg,
    chat_message.type_message,
    chat_message.url_file,
    chat_message.url_file,
    chat_message.was_removed,
    chat_message.was_removed
FROM chat_message
INNER JOIN user_profile_userprofile
    ON chat_message.owner_id = user_profile_userprofile.id
INNER JOIN auth_user
    ON user_profile_userprofile.user_id = auth_user.id
WHERE chat_message.chat_room_id = 7204712
AND NOT chat_message.delete_by::text LIKE '%fattimita08%'
ORDER BY chat_message.id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Duration: 11956.422

Definitions for involved tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.chat_message (
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('chat_message_id_seq'::regclass)
, chat_room_id integer NOT NULL
, owner_id integer NOT NULL
, info_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
, aud_msg character varying(500) NOT NULL
, vid_msg character varying(500) NOT NULL
, img_msg character varying(500) NOT NULL
, text_msg text NOT NULL
, type_message smallint NOT NULL
, delete_by character varying(50) NOT NULL
, url_file character varying(1000) NOT NULL
, receiver_id integer
, info_date_str character varying(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2019-11-28 23:43:44.578419'
, was_removed boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false
, CONSTRAINT chat_message_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
, CONSTRAINT chat_messag_receiver_id_0eceddde_fk_user_profile_userprofile_id FOREIGN KEY (receiver_id) REFERENCES public.user_profile_userprofile (id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
, CONSTRAINT chat_message_chat_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (chat_room_id) REFERENCES public.chat_chat (id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
, CONSTRAINT chat_message_owner_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES public.user_profile_userprofile (id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);

CREATE INDEX chat_room_id_idx ON public.chat_message (chat_room_id);
CREATE INDEX owner_id_idx     ON public.chat_message (owner_id);
CREATE INDEX receiver_id_idx  ON public.chat_message (receiver_id);


CREATE TABLE public.user_profile_userprofile (
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_profile_userprofile_id_seq'::regclass)
, user_id integer NOT NULL
, birthdate date
, profile_picture character varying(500) NOT NULL
, country character varying(500) NOT NULL
, phrase character varying(300) NOT NULL
, is_mod boolean NOT NULL
, ip inet, id_cel character varying(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
, twitter_key character varying(500) DEFAULT ''
, twitter_secret character varying(500) DEFAULT ''
, gender character varying(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
, lastseen character varying(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
, profile_video character varying(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
, status character varying(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
, name character varying(500) NOT NULL
, "id_timeZone" character varying(500) NOT NULL
, profile_picture_thumb character varying(500) NOT NULL
, city character varying(500) NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT user_profile_userprofile_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
, CONSTRAINT user_profile_userprofile_user_id_key UNIQUE (user_id)
, CONSTRAINT cascade_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES public.auth_user (id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX userprofile_user_idx ON public.user_profile_userprofile (user_id);


CREATE TABLE public.auth_user (
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('auth_user_id_seq'::regclass)
, password character varying(128) NOT NULL
, last_login timestamp with time zone
, is_superuser boolean NOT NULL
, username character varying(150) NOT NULL
, first_name character varying(30) NOT NULL
, last_name character varying(30) NOT NULL
, email character varying(254) NOT NULL
, is_staff boolean NOT NULL
, is_active boolean NOT NULL
, date_joined timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT auth_user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
, CONSTRAINT auth_user_username_key UNIQUE (username)
);

CREATE INDEX auth_user_username_like ON public.auth_user (username varchar_pattern_ops);
CREATE INDEX username_idx ON public.auth_user (username);
```

I used this query to analyze:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "chat_message"."info_date_str", "auth_user"."username", "chat_message"."id", "chat_message"."text_msg", "chat_message"."type_message", "chat_message"."url_file", "chat_message"."url_file", "chat_message"."was_removed", "chat_message"."was_removed" FROM "chat_message" INNER JOIN "user_profile_userprofile" ON ("chat_message"."owner_id" = "user_profile_userprofile"."id") INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("user_profile_userprofile"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id") WHERE ("chat_message"."chat_room_id" = 7204712 AND NOT ("chat_message"."delete_by"::text LIKE '%fattimita08%')) ORDER BY "chat_message"."id" DESC LIMIT 20
```

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=33503.90..33614.03 rows=20 width=87) (actual time=5753.937..5754.447 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=33503.90..85612.86 rows=9463 width=87) (actual time=5753.935..5754.443 rows=20 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=33503.48..63940.73 rows=9463 width=80) (actual time=5753.923..5754.399 rows=20 loops=1)
              ->  Gather Merge  (cost=33503.06..34605.18 rows=9463 width=80) (actual time=5753.893..5754.349 rows=20 loops=1)
                    Workers Planned: 2
                    Workers Launched: 0
                    ->  Sort  (cost=32503.03..32512.89 rows=3943 width=80) (actual time=5753.535..5753.540 rows=20 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: chat_message.id DESC
                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2477kB
                          ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on chat_message  (cost=129.77..32267.53 rows=3943 width=80) (actual time=81.934..5741.308 rows=10447 loops=1)
                                Recheck Cond: (chat_room_id = 7204712)
                                Filter: ((delete_by)::text !~~ '%fattimita08%'::text)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                Heap Blocks: exact=8278
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on chat_room_id_idx  (cost=0.00..127.41 rows=9463 width=0) (actual time=63.921..63.922 rows=10448 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (chat_room_id = 7204712)
              ->  Memoize  (cost=0.43..4.95 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=20)
                    Cache Key: chat_message.owner_id
                    Cache Mode: logical
                    Hits: 18  Misses: 2  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 1kB
                    ->  Index Scan using user_profile_userprofile_pkey on user_profile_userprofile  (cost=0.42..4.94 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=2)
                          Index Cond: (id = chat_message.owner_id)
        ->  Index Scan using auth_user_pkey on auth_user  (cost=0.42..2.29 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=20)
              Index Cond: (id = user_profile_userprofile.user_id)
Planning Time: 43.104 ms
Execution Time: 5754.630 ms
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248396/discussion-on-question-by-hvar90-query-with-small-limit-gets-slow-with-many-hits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main hardship for this query is that it filters by `chat_room_id`, but sorts by `id` (descending) - before a very small `LIMIT`.

Postgres expects the filter `chat_room_id = 7204712` to be selective and starts with a bitmap heap scan on `chat_room_id_idx`, finding ~ 10k rows.

The additional filter `AND NOT chat_message.delete_by::text LIKE '%fattimita08%'` seems hardly selective. (BTW, the cast (`::text`) in that expression does nothing useful, drop it.)

This [multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) should give you faster results, by orders of magnitude:

```sql
CREATE INDEX chat_message_your_name_here_idx ON public.chat_message (chat_room_id, id DESC);
```

Now Postgres can just walk the index with an index scan, and filter the few rows that should not qualify.

Related:

- [Optimize a query with small LIMIT, predicate on one column and order by another](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/124817/3684)

That said, the `Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on chat_message` is responsible for the lion share of the cost - a cost that seems excessive for just `rows=10447`. Is that table particularly big? Do you have decent hardware? Maybe the table is bloated? Are matching rows spread out over the big table physically? Depending on the actual diagnosis, `VACUUM`, or even `VACUUM FULL`, or better yet `CLUSTER` on the new index might help (a lot). Like:

```
CLUSTER public.chat_message USING chat_message_your_name_here_idx;
```

Be aware that's expensive and blocking for a big table. There are non-blocking alternatives. See:

- [Optimize Postgres query on timestamp range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998139/optimize-postgres-query-on-timestamp-range/14007963#14007963)
- [PostgreSQL index not used for query on IP ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407719/postgresql-index-not-used-for-query-on-ip-ranges/14407839#14407839)
- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39599/3684)

Comment: thanks, those are the new indexes i need, i will test it, by the way, how could i learn to do that kind of analysis? how could i learn to put all the indexes? i have more slow queries to speed up but i dont know how to put the indexes

Comment: @hvar90: I added some more advice and a couple of links with hooks for optimizing ...

Comment: thanks :) and the size of table message is 
2.1 GB
the database server has
vCPU
2
RAM
4 GB

Comment: More RAM, better CPU, and proper server configuration should help quite a bit, too.

Comment: Is there any real value in the `DESC` part of the index?

Comment: @TheImpaler: The Postgres query planner estimates the same cost for `Index (Only) Scan` and `Index Only Scan Backward`. In reality, `Backward` costs a tiny bit more. Hardly matters for the query at hand, an index on `(chat_room_id, id)` would be equally good. But if NULL values can be involved, or once we actually `CLUSTER` on that index, the difference becomes more real. With queries that sort on both columns in opposing directions, or with opposing range conditions, the difference becomes very real. Like: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39599/3684

Comment: someone said me "Searches like '%fattima% cannot be optimized no matter what index. Look into full text search ability of SQL server."
is it true? %fattima% makes slow the query?

Comment: when i did the query on pgadmin4 the query is fast, it takes 388ms, i dont know why on RDS console it takes so long

Comment: @hvar90: That someone is wrong. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/939860 However, while that predicate is hardly selective (`Rows Removed by Filter: 1`), not even a trigram can help. pgAdmin is just another client, shouldn't influence server execution time at all. You may be looking at the wrong metric. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/316494/3684

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks, using that multicolumn index  is faster now 
Planning Time: 0.874 ms
Execution Time: 0.264 ms